# How to get JSON data using service in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I am facing problem to get the array of JSON data by using service in Angular.js

```
<body ng-app="filterApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
     <div ng-repeat="aa in myData">
      {{aa}}
       </div>
</body>
```

Js:

```
var app = angular.module('filterApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
$http.get('data.json').
   then(function (response) {
       $scope.myData = response.data;
       console.log($scope.myData);
   });
});
```

Json data:

```
[
  {
   "name":"ss",
    "id":1
},
  {
    "name":"pp",
    "id":2
  }
]
```

Comment: add the close tag to body tag

Comment: is there any object named "data" in the json response?

Comment: no @ Akash Agrawal

Comment: try this $scope.myData = response;

Comment: what you get if you use `console.log(response)`

Comment: I tried but iam unable to see in console @ Akash Agrawal

Comment: @swathi, can you create a fiddle?

Comment: try replacing .then by .success. You'll get to know if there's any problem with data.json call or not